# Can you use android.os.Build.getSerial() with Robolectric?

Tags: android, mockito, robolectric

I have been using Robolectric to unit test a library (no app). I seem to be able to access Build.SERIAL and change the value, but I have been unable to find a way to do Build.getSerial() (Which is required for Android P). I tried to get PowerMockito to mock the method, though you aren't really supposed to mock android classes, but I couldn't get Robolectric/PowerMockito/Gradle to work together.

I'd also be happy with a solution where Build.getSerial() doesn't throw a NullPointerException when used. A null value is fine as long as I can skip the exception.

Answer (score 1):

This function is supported in Robolectric 4.0.
https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/releases/tag/robolectric-4.0-beta-3